# From 2019/03/27, why some of ios device can not receive fcm message?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Our system pushes message to iOS app three times a day(per 75k at a time,total 230k a day).

For example, at 27 March 2019, we pushed 230k to Firebase, and Firebase returned about 220k for "Success"(we count this number in our system and it was normal at this step). But in Firebase Website, we saw Firebase sent only 170k to app(according to the picture). And at this day, we saw iOS app activeness which was reduced 20% according to our system.

And at 3 April 2019, we saw Firebase sent only 98k to app! This Problem appeared everyday until now and we did not change any push code. It is strange!

Can you tell me what is happenning when Firebase pushes the message to app? Why it reduces quite a few?  Did the problem relate to the SDK version or certificate update or PHP push parameters? Do you have any Error Log for the problem? I am confused. Please help me! Thanks!